# Change active transparent .png background color in python

Tags: python, background, png, gimp

I am trying to automate this [Gimp Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44RBo.png), which can change the active background color in a transparent .png file from white to black. The background is somehow saved with the picture but still stays transparent. I could not reproduce this feature anywhere else in another program, but need that for a project.

I tried it like this (runs through all images in my input folder and puts it afterwards as a new file in the output folder, image size is 9150*10980 px).

```
import random
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
import glob

def background_apply(input_image_path,
 output_image_path):
 photo = Image.open(input_image_path).convert('RGBA')
 img2 = Image.new('RGBA', (9150, 10980))
 print (photo.mode)
 img2.paste(photo, mask=photo)

img2.save(output_image_path)

list = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\XX\input\*.*")

for photo in list:

 out = photo.replace('input','output')
 background_apply(photo,
 out)
```

This saves my image with a transparent background, but not with the desired "black transparent". I hope I made the problem clear, it is not that I want to get a real black background on the image, it should still stay transparent.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, GIMP is open source so you can freely look up how they do it, but my guess is that they change the color of the RGB pixels to the desired one per each fully transparent Alpha channel pixel. Does that make sense? An image can have color on fully transparent pixels, since the transparency is stored in a separate layer, so you can just look at that layer, grab all the pixel locations that are fully transparent, then re-use those locations on the RGB channels to set the color.

Comment: icon you show doesn't elicit a color replacement in the image. It merely swaps the colors that are used with the paint tools. It just happens that you can ask Gimp to set the fully transparent pixels to the background color when you export.

Comment: Kindly show an image before and after your desired adjustment so we can see what you are trying to do. Thank you.